# Unittest a function which uses a lambda expresssion

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, python-unittest

I have a function which internally uses lambda expression for processing. I need to write unit tests for this function. When i run my python unit test using the command :
python -m unittest discover -v , the unit test infinitely waits for the callback function (in this case lambda expression).

Can we unittest such cases

Sample code (abc.py)

```
def uses_callback_func():

    super_sf= Sframe()
    .... # some other code for sframe creation.
    super_sf['weighted_innsa'] = super_sf.apply(lambda x:
                                                2.0 if (x['from_id'] =='INNSA' or x['to_id'] == 'INNSA') # unittest halts at this line.
                                                else 1.0)
     return len(super_sf['weighted_innsa']
```

test_abc.py

```
  def test_callback_func(self):
       value_1 = abc.uses_callback_func()    
       assertEqual(value_1, 3)
```

Comment: Why is it a lambda? Just write a regular function, then testing will be trivial.

Comment: Yes in this case in can do it, but in the code base there are other callback functions which can't be replaced by regular function. Added this code base just as an example.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - what's an `Sframe`, for example?

Comment: The question is invalid, libfaketime library i am using causing the callback function to loop infinitely. Question is invalid in that case. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: In that case, please delete it.